# ST_Transform returning different results in PostGIS 2.4 and PostGIS 3.0

Tags: postgis, point, srid, st, postgis-3.0

I am facing a problem with the function `st_transform()`and here is my analysis of this pb:

Example of SQL query with different results depending on PostGIS version:

```
select st_astext(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(398845.80866241, 6822815.8927889), 2154), 932001))
```

Projection 932001 to insert in spatial_ref_sys for testing :

```
INSERT into spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, proj4text, srtext) values ( 932001, 'IGNF' , 320002101 , '+proj=lcc +nadgrids=ntf_r93.gsb,null +a=6378249.2000 +rf=293.4660210000000 +pm=2.337229167 +lat_0=49.500000000 +lon_0=0.000000000 +k_0=0.99987734 +lat_1=49.500000000 +x_0=600000.000 +y_0=200000.000 +units=m +no_defs' , 'PROJCS["Lambert I",GEOGCS["Nouvelle Triangulation Française Paris grades",DATUM["NTF",SPHEROID["Clarke 1880 IGN",6378249.2000,293.4660210000000,AUTHORITY["IGNF","ELG010"]],TOWGS84[-168.0000,-60.0000,320.0000,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["IGNF","REG002"]],PRIMEM["Paris",2.337229167,AUTHORITY["IGNF","LGO02"]],UNIT["grad",0.01570796326794897],AXIS["Longitude",EAST],AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],AUTHORITY["IGNF","NTFP"]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_1SP",AUTHORITY["IGNF","PRC0101"]],PARAMETER["semi_major",6378249.2000],PARAMETER["semi_minor",6356515.0000],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",49.500000000],PARAMETER["central_meridian",0.000000000],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.99987734],PARAMETER["false_easting",600000.000],PARAMETER["false_northing",200000.000],UNIT["metre",1],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["IGNF","LAMB1"]]');
```

This projection 932001 corresponds to Lambert Zone 1 corrected with the IGN grid.

On our PostgreSQL 10 / PostGIS 2.4 machine, we get:

```
POINT(347762.11171084 87364.0318659853)
```

While in PostgresQL 13 / PostGIS 3.0, we get this (result which is incorrect):

```
POINT(347200.5307476731 637506.2948565462)
```

Result of the query select postgis_full_version(); on our 2 environments:

```
PostgreSQL 10 : POSTGIS="2.4.7 r17330" PGSQL="100" GEOS="3.7.1-CAPI-1.11.1 27a5e771" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" GDAL="GDAL 2.3.2, released 2018/09/21" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="0.11" RASTER



PostgresSQL 13 : POSTGIS="3.1.8 c5ebc1f" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="130" GEOS="3.10.3-CAPI-1.16.1" PROJ="8.2.1" LIBXML="2.9.7" LIBJSON="0.13.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.0" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)" TOPOLOGY
```

What solution can make this work with PostGIS 3.x?

Comment: what exactly is the difference in results?

Comment: The points are different POINT(347762.11171084 87364.0318659853) and POINT(347200.5307476731 637506.2948565462)

Comment: @IanTurton, when i run my select st_astext(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(398845.80866241, 6822815.8927889), 2154), 932001)) on both machines with different postgis versions, i get different results, the POINT is not exactly the same

Comment: You are using different versions of the Proj library, and they might or might not actually be able to find the ntf_r93.gsb file. Please tell us the OS and how you have installed PG and the extra projection data.

Comment: @CL. , i looked on both environments and the ntf_r93.gsb file exists on both installations. We installed it as a docker images on Ubuntu systems

Comment: Does "it" refer to PostGIS or the projection file? If it's the first, did you add the file manually?

Comment: Beginning with Proj 7, the file has different contents and must be named [fr_ign_ntf_r93.tif](https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ-data/tree/master/fr_ign).

Comment: @CL. so i installed this fr_ign_ntf_r93.tif and i redid my tests, however i still have the same results, this is the updated proj4text i used:
 '+proj=lcc +nadgrids=fr_ign_ntf_rg93.tif,ntf_r93.gsb,null +a=6378249.2000 +rf=293.4660210000000 +pm=2.337229167 +lat_0=49.500000000 +lon_0=0.000000000 +k_0=0.99987734 +lat_1=49.500000000 +x_0=600000.000 +y_0=200000.000 +units=m +no_defs'

Comment: Where and how did you install it? How did you determine the [directory](https://proj.org/en/9.2/resource_files.html)?

Comment: @CL. i installed it from the github link you previously shared. as for the path, i looked up where the ntf_r93.gsb file was located in postgis 2, which was /usr/share/proj/ and i moved the fr_ign_ntf_r93.tif to the same location in my postgis 3 installation.

Comment: I do not know if that is the correct path on your system (are the other PROJ files there?), or whether or not it must be in the fr_ign subdirectory.

Comment: @CL. is there a way to verify the correct path of the PROJ files? i looked it up everywhere and i only found that its in /usr/share/proj/.
i have the fr_ign subdirectory with the fr_ign_ntf_r93.tif inside and yet i am still getting the same results.

Comment: I guess you have to ask on the [PROJ mailing list](https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/proj).

Comment: File missing from the package: https://cdn.proj.org/fr_ign_ntf_r93.tif to be deposited in the PROJ installation directory for Centos/RHEL 8 (for my example, I deposited it via Filezilla in /tmp, and then copied it to the PROJ82 directory)

bash
#root mv /tmp/frignntf_r93.tif /usr/proj82/share/proj/
#root chmod 644 /usr/proj82/share/proj/frignntf_r93.tif
Sources:

https://proj.org/en/9.3/community/rfc/rfc-4.html

http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2023/02/proj-network.html

https://cdn.proj.org

This solution was implemented by INTM for ENEDIS.